# A way to create a variable that includes a modifier that should be checked every step [Gamemaker]

Tags: game-maker

I can't tell if I am being stupid, but I am looking for a way in Gamemaker to have a variable include a modifier which has the potential to change every step.

This variable is called `mTiredness`, and I would like it to include the `TimeOfDayModifier` which needs to be checked frequently.

However, I obviously can't put

`mTiredness = mTiredness + TimeOfDayModifier`

in a Step event, as this would add the modifier, in my case, 60 times a second, which I do not want!

Instead, I want a **consistent** variable comprised of the base amount and the modifier, while allowing that modifier to change.

Can anybody help me? I cannot think of an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a script. It's a function actually, so you can make it return the sum you desire. That way you don't affect the `mTiredness` value. You will only need to have global access to those variables or either pass them as arguments/parameters.

Comment: Right, so I just use the `return` function in that script, and then place the script in a step event? I knew there was a simple way to do this, thanks!